# animate -- timeline question

Tags: animate

I am using the animate package in a very intense way. But unfortunately the file increases if I will not use the timeline feature.
Assume the following scenario.

I am going to draw a graph. But this is highly animated. There is a handy including a pen which follows the path. 
Single pdfs are created with pstricks. See at the link to the pdfs. There are all sources which can be used to reduce file size.
The example is only part of the full animated script, only the first 5 or 6 linesegments are printed.

as far as I understand, timeline allows to use frames, overlays and also javascript. But I dont understand, how to move the hand along the path. The source animated curve was a little bit tricky, because I had to calculate intersectionpoints to make this animation work. Look at the following code.

Source is available at http://docdro.id/2ajuDhG where all singleframes are attached via attachfile2 package. You can download this file and extract single frames as well as desired result file which is also included. The filesize is much to big.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{animate,media9}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{attachfile2}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\animategraphics[trim=4.75cm 11cm 5.5cm 4.0cm,poster=last,autoplay=false,autoresume=true,autopause=true,loop=false,controls=true,method=ocg,timeline=tlfile.txt,scale=0.75]{1}{pdstests-}{1}{7}
 \caption{test}
\end{figure}

 \begin{lstlisting}
::0x7
::1x6
::2x5
::3x4
::4x3
::5x2
::6x1 
 \end{lstlisting}

 \begin{lstlisting}[breaklines=true]
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{animate,media9}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{attachfile2}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\animategraphics[trim=4.75cm 11cm 5.5cm 4.0cm,poster=last,autoplay=false,autoresume=true,autopause=true,loop=false,controls=true,method=ocg,timeline=tlfile.txt,scale=0.75]{1}{pdstests-}{1}{7}
 \caption{test}
\end{figure}
\end{document}

 \end{lstlisting}

 \begin{itemize}
\item pdstests-8 \attachfile[mimetype=application/pdf, color={0.2 0.65 1},icon=Paperclip,description=pdstests-8]{pdstests-8.pdf}
\item pdstests-7 \attachfile[mimetype=application/pdf, color={0.2 0.65 1},icon=Paperclip,description=pdstests-7]{pdstests-7.pdf}
\item pdstests-6 \attachfile[mimetype=application/pdf, color={0.2 0.65 1},icon=Paperclip,description=pdstests-6]{pdstests-6.pdf}
\item pdstests-5 \attachfile[mimetype=application/pdf, color={0.2 0.65 1},icon=Paperclip,description=pdstests-5]{pdstests-5.pdf}
\item pdstests-4 \attachfile[mimetype=application/pdf, color={0.2 0.65 1},icon=Paperclip,description=pdstests-4]{pdstests-4.pdf}
\item pdstests-3 \attachfile[mimetype=application/pdf, color={0.2 0.65 1},icon=Paperclip,description=pdstests-3]{pdstests-3.pdf}
\item pdstests-2 \attachfile[mimetype=application/pdf, color={0.2 0.65 1},icon=Paperclip,description=pdstests-2]{pdstests-2.pdf}
\item pdstests-1 \attachfile[mimetype=application/pdf, color={0.2 0.65 1},icon=Paperclip,description=pdstests-1]{pdstests-1.pdf}
\item Result \attachfile[mimetype=application/pdf, color={0.2 0.65 1},icon=Paperclip,description=Resultfile]{Resultfile.pdf}
 \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Any Ideas how do overlay lines AND move one frame down? Maybe the new frame feature will do the job, but won't the file be as big as before, will it?